# Efficient way of comparing value in array to all values before in array

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, algorithm

I have a very long array numbers[]. My algorithm needs to find the lowest index j in numbers[] at which the `|numbers[j] - numbers[i]| <= x`(a random variable) or where  `|numbers[j] - numbers[i]| >= m - x` (m another variable, larger than x) and where `i<j`.

This is my algorithm now:

```
 for (int j = 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
     {
        long diff = Math.Abs(numbers[j] - numbers[i]); 
        if (diff <= x || diff >= m - x)
            return j;
     }
 }
```

Can this be done more efficiently? An input with very high numbers, for instance, takes my laptop about 36 seconds.

Comment: This isn't included in the explanation `|| diff >= m - x`

Comment: Is there an upper limit on the numbers and the `x`, other than the implied limit of `Int32.MaxValue`?

Comment: the largest x can be is 10 million, the other values ( in the array) can be up to 100 billion.

Comment: Just by curiosity, what is the purpose of the algorithm? What do you do with the `j` index? Why not returning `i` as well?

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the array?

Comment: Its for an assignment for a university, the numbers are actually calculated using a formula. And I can sort the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in O(nlogn) by iterating through the array and at each stage adding the new number to a balanced search tree.

When you add the number you first search for the closest number already in the search tree.  If this number is less than the target difference then you have found the answer.

Comment: A balanced search tree is a bit too much code to add to the answer, but I've found a plausible implementation [here](http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/efficient-avl-tree-in-c-sharp.aspx)